# Buefy switch not applying to rows

Tags: php, bulma

I am fetching some results in a loop which is then output into a table - but when applying a 'switch' element from Buefy (Bulma UI kit) it will only apply it to the first item in the row and not anything following.

Here is the HTML of my loop:

```
        <?php
        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * 
                                 FROM dashboard");
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll();
        ?>

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="dashTable">

        <div class="header">
            <div class="col">Name</div>
            <div class="col">Status</div>
            <div class="col">Created</div>
            <div class="col">Options</div>
        </div>

<?php foreach($result as $row){ ?>
        <div class="body">


            <div class="col">
            <a title="View New Dashboard" href="../loading.php?dashboard_id=50">
                <?php
                 echo $row['name'];
                 ?>
            </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <!-- CLICK TO UPDATE STATUS -->
                status
                <div id="app1">
                <template>
                    <section>
                        <div class="field">
                            <b-switch v-model="isSwitchedCustom"
                                true-value="Active"
                                false-value="Inactive" type="is-success">
                                {{ isSwitchedCustom }}
                            </b-switch>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </template>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col"><?php echo date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime($row['created_at']) ); ?></div>
            <div class="col">
                <span class="tag is-warning is-medium">
                  Edit
                </span>
                <span id="confirm-delete" class="tag is-danger is-medium" @click="confirmCustomDelete">
                  Delete
                </span>
            </div>

        </div>  
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am just not sure why after the first it does not apply to all rows?

Comment: you are only fetching one result, not all results, the part where you are doing the fetching is not given in your question

Comment: @Nathanael I have added the method of me selecting the data from the DB to my question - I hope this helps?